# Define "order" in Triangle Law of vector addition

Tags: vectors

Triangle Law of vector addition states that-

> When two vectors are represented by two sides of a triangle in
> magnitude and direction taken in the same **order** (or, *sequence*)
> then third side of the triangle represents in magnitude and direction
> the resultant of those two vectors in reverse **order**.

What I can't really comprehend is what is meant by the word "order". Apart from this law, I found the word "order" is used in certain practice problems in vector mechanics. After looking some YouTube videos and giving a few Google search I was told that "two sides in same order" means two sides of the triangle is taken tail to head and "reverse order" means head to tail. But I still can't comprehend it much and relate it to the practice problems properly. Can someone please elaborate the use of the word "order" here and what it properly means? Also is the use of "order" limited to triangle's only or it applies to all sorts of polygon?